# Simpler way to replace digits from Int array?

Tags: java

If I have two ints
Goal - replace last 3 digits of x1 by x2

```
int x1 = 1000;
int x2 = 3; //x2 can't be larger than 999

char[] digits = String.valueOf(x1).toCharArray();
char[] digits2 = String.valueOf(x2).toCharArray();

if(digits2.length == 3) {
 replace digits[1],[2],[3] by digits[0,1,2]
}
if(digits2.length == 2) {
     replace digits[2,3] by digits[0,1] and replace digits[1] by 0
}
if(digits.length == 1) {
     replace digits[3] by digits[0] and digits[1,2,] by 0
}

x1 = Integer.parseInt(new String(digits));
```

Question - Is it neccesary to have the three if conditionals, or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no int array in your code.

Replacing the last three digits of a positive integer by the last three digits of a postitive integer just requires a bit of math :

```
x1 = (x1/1000)*1000 + x2%1000;
```

`(x1/1000)*1000` zeroes the last 3 digits of `x1` because / does integer division when applied to integer types.
x2%1000 results in only the 3 last digits of `x2`.
And the sum is the result you want.

Things get a bit more complicated if negative numbers are involved.

If we make use of the fact that the question states that `x2` can't be greater than 999 we can simplify the code to :

```
x1 = (x1/1000)*1000 + x2;
```